# HTTP GET request with locale

Tags: http

Sometimes when I navigate to a website, the GET request is:

`GET /se/ HTTP/1.1`

How is the locale being added instead of just the root? From what I see it is the first request I send to the server. Is my browser adding this in? If so, how does it know to add it for some sites and not others?

Comment: Not enough info here. It is _not_ a convention in any way to request `/{countrycode}/` instead of `/`. Use a tool like Fiddler and inspect the HTTP requests and their responses.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the server redirected your request to '/se/' based on the your preferred language that is detected from `Accept-Language` header in your request.

Answer (score 0):

The server can have whatever rules it likes to do this. Generally, as @npcode mentioned, `Accept-Language` should be used, but it's possible that the website in question is directing you there based on ip geocoding rules. If you connect via a proxy in another country, does it still happen?